# Is H2 database compatible with Oracle 'Insert All' statement?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, integration-testing, h2

I'm writing tests for MyBatis DAO layer for Oracle database and have a problem with batch insert operation. It is implemented with Oracle statement `INSERT ALL`:

```
<insert id="batchInsertElements" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="false">
    INSERT ALL
    <foreach collection="list" item="element">
        INTO table1
        (
        col1, col2, col3, col4
        )
        VALUES
        (
        #{element.col1},
        (select nvl(c.ID, -1) from table2 c where c.name = #{element.col2}),
        #{element.col3},
        #{element.col4}
        )
    </foreach>
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
</insert>
```

Against real database, it is working with no errors. For tests, I'm using H2 database and spring-dbunit. Configuration for test database:

```
<bean id="testDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

During a test for the batch insert I'm getting SQL syntax error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT ALL[*]

        INTO TABLE1
        (
        COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
        )
        VALUES
        (
        ?,
        (SELECT NVL(C.ID, -1) FROM TABLE2 C WHERE C.NAME = ?),
        ?,
        ?
        )

    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL "; expected "INTO";
 [42001-193]; bad SQL grammar [];
```

I'm suspecting that `INSERT ALL` statement is not supported by H2 database. Is it so? Any workaround? Can HSQLDB be more suitable for Oracle DAO testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither H2 nor HSQLDB supports the Oracle proprietary `INSERT ALL` syntax. Short of having an instance of Oracle up and running for your unit/integration tests, I'm not sure there is another way around it. You could look into using a dockerized Oracle XE container and spin it up as part of your test. Another option would be to get developers to look into moving away from the `INSERT ALL`.

Comment: thanks! Where do you find the list of supported operations?

Comment: From each respective general documentation.  Here is a link for H2 SQL Grammar [sql-grammer](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html).  Here is the SQL Index appendix for HSQLDB [sql-index](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sql-ind.html)